# Centos htop Java Tomcat high processor usage

Tags: java, tomcat, process, centos

On my centos 7 I have a strange high processor usage peaks up to 100% every few seconds (looking with htop)

this is the line of the process:

```
/usr/java/jdk-10.0.2/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0022 -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC -Dignore.endorsed.dirs= -classpath /opt/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/temp org.apa
```

can you help me debug it?

Comment: Why do you expect no peak usage? The JVM does something and needs CPU. You should check the VM by making stack traces in case of high load. Not sure if "jvisualvm" exists and can be used on your system.

Comment: I was getting worried cause I have the same thing installed on other Centos server but the JDK is 8, I have no processes there that go over 10 %

Comment: Garbage Collector typically consumes CPU. We see you tuned a very small heap (512M/1024M) which could explain the need of garbaging very often. With a bigger heap size, you would garbage less often but during a longer time. You can add GC system properties then you will see GC activity in the logs, and you will confirm if this CPU peak is GC related. Hope it helps.

Comment: Will try this. Thank you!